# FullCalendar in Laravel Nova Component

Tags: laravel, vue.js, fullcalendar

I have a problem with FullCalendar in Laravel Nova Tool.
I've created the Tool and I can display the events in generated calendar. The problem is with the localisation and the height of the calendar. Here some code:

```
<template >
<div>
<FullCalendar
@dateClick="handleDateClick"
@eventClick="handleEventClick"
@eventMouseEnter="handleMouseEnter"
@eventMouseLeave="handleMouseLeave"
ref="fullCalendar"
:plugins="calendarPlugins"
:weekends="calendarWeekends"
:events="calendarEvents"
:config="{
  locale: 'it', <============
  height: '200'<========
}"
:header="{
  left: 'prev,next today',
  center: 'title',
  right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,listWeek'
}"

/>
</div>
</template>
<script>
...
mounted() {
    axios.get('/nova-vendor/fullcalendar/produzioni').then(response => {
       //get the events
    }
}
</script>
```

The config section is ignored, or is inserted in the wrong place.
Can you help me?
Thanks!

Roberto

Comment: Why did you decide to put it inside a "config" option? There's no such thing in the fullCalendar docs. Those options should be directly in your list along with the others. I'm not familiar with the specific wrapper syntax in your code but you should at least follow the documented structure. I would expect that `... :events="calendarEvents"
  :locale= 'it'
  :height='200'
:header="{ ...` should probably work. No idea where you got the "config" idea from.

Comment: P.s. it's unclear what the purpose of `ref="fullCalendar"` would be, either

Comment: I have found this code in some other example. With `:locale= 'it' :height='200'` it works but: 1) locale is always in `en`, even if I have imported: `import it from '@fullcalendar/core/locales/it';` 2) how I can set the height to 100% of parent div? Now I have a scrollbar on the right...

Comment: See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/height for how to configure the height. (Hint: read about the "parent" setting)

Comment: Already tried, doesn't works.

Comment: is your parent element smaller or larger than the natural height of the calendar? Here's a demo (using vanilla fullCalendar) where the parent is smaller: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/rELXvJ . And one where it's larger: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/vYYWXwX . Both work fine. It's unclear, without knowing the height, what the problem might be in your case. Both demos also have the locale working correctly. I'm not familiar with the vue.js syntax unfortunately, so I apologise if that's the issue. Maybe someone with vue experience can help with that.

Comment: P.S. the locale thing might be because you have to specify the variable `it` not the string `'it'` (as per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/locale) - try `:locale= it` instead.

Comment: In the same vein, try `:height = 200` instead of `:height= '200'` if you want to set a number (rather than "parent") - if you set a numbered height then it's supposed to be an integer not a string.